# Checking a string for adjacent keyboard characters

Tags: python, data-structures, keyboard

I'm trying to see if characters in a string are adjacent on the keyboard.

This code initializes the keyboard as the 3d array "Array3":

```
KeyboardRow1 = ["`", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "0", "-", "=", ""]
KeyboardRow2 = ["", "q", "w", "e", "r", "t", "y", "u", "i", "o", "p", "[", "]", ""] 
KeyboardRow3 = ["", "a", "s", "d", "f", "g", "h", "j", "k", "l", ";", "", "", ""] 
KeyboardRow4 = ["", "z", "x", "c", "v", "b", "n", "m", ",", ".", "/", "", "", ""]
KeyboardRow1S = ["~", "!", "@", "#", "$", "%", "^", "&", "*", "(", ")", "_", "+", ""]
KeyboardRow2S = ["", "Q", "W", "E", "R", "T", "Y", "U", "I", "O", "P", "{", "}", "|"]
KeyboardRow3S = ["","A", "S", "D", "F", "G", "H", "J", "K", "L", ":", "", "", ""] 
KeyboardRow4S = ["", "Z", "X", "C", "V", "B", "N", "M", "<", ">", "?", "", "", ""]
Array2R = [KeyboardRow1, KeyboardRow2, KeyboardRow3, KeyboardRow4]
Array2S = [KeyboardRow1S, KeyboardRow2S, KeyboardRow3S, KeyboardRow4S]
Array3 = [Array2R, Array2S]
```

This code turns each character of the entered password into coordinates of where it is in the array and stores those coordinates in KeyboardPositions.

```
KeyboardPositions = []
for z in range(0,PasswordLength):
    for i in range(2):
        for j in range(4):
            for k in range (14):
                if Password[z] == str(Array3[i][j][k]):
                    KeyboardPositions.append((i,j,k))
```

This code, where I am having trouble, checks for adjacency.

```
  for x in range(PasswordLength-1):
        for y in range(3):
            if KeyboardPositions[x][y] == (KeyboardPositions[x+1][y]-1) or KeyboardPositions[x][y] == (KeyboardPositions[x+1][y]+1):
                Adjacency = Adjacency + 1

print("There are " + str(Adjacency) + " adjacent characters")
```

What the last piece of code is trying to do is see if the row, column or shift (if shift is held, 1 or 0) coordinates are +- 1 of each other. However, it counts things like "t" and "a" adjacent, because they are only 1 row apart. How can I fix this ? Thanks

Comment: Do you consider diagonal keys as adjacent?  For example, "a" and "w", or "q" and "s"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you assign a number to each character in keyboard and check if they are neighbor by subtracting them? Something like this:
First define a dictionary to store the numbers:

```
n = {}

n['q'] = 1
n['w'] = 2
n['e'] = 3
... n['p'] = 10
```

And for the second row, start counting from 20, to avoid `a` and `p` becomes neighbour:

```
n['a'] = 20
n['s'] = 21
... n['l'] = 28
```

Then, you can use this function:

```
def check_neighbourhood(a,b):
    return n[a] == n[b] or abs(n[a] - n[b]) == 1 or abs(n[a] - n[b]) == 19
```

`n[a] - n[q] = 19`, So we should handle this one.

Answer (score 0):

I'd do it this way (assume KeyboardRowN are present in the code):

```
from itertools import combinations

Rows = [KeyboardRow1, KeyboardRow2, KeyboardRow3, KeyboardRow4, \
        KeyboardRow1S, KeyboardRow2S, KeyboardRow3S, KeyboardRow4S]

row_len = len(KeyboardRow1)

def pass2index(passwd):
    """Produce a list of pairs (coordinates) for each character of a given passphrase. 
    Each pair encodes row and column in a list of keyboard keys."""
    coordinates = []
    for c in passwd:
        for i, r in enumerate(Rows):
            # check if password's char is in the current row
            try:
                # modulo 4 used for shifted keys,
                # so that 'k' and 'K' have the same row index
                coordinates.append((i % 4, r.index(c)))
            except:
                pass
    return coordinates

def adjacency(coords):
    """Produce a number of adjacency for a list of coordinates."""
    adjacent = 0
    # produce combinations of coordinates to compare each two letters
    # i.e. combinations of two coordinates
    for pairs in combinations(coords, 2):
        # two coordinates are adjacent if their rows and columns
        # differ by +/- 1
        if (abs(pairs[0][0] - pairs[1][0]) < 2) \
           and (abs(pairs[0][1] - pairs[1][1]) < 2):
            # print(pairs) # used for examples below
            adjacent += 1
    return adjacent
```

The code is well commented, so hopefully you don't need additional explanations for it.

You can check it as follows (I commented out `print(pairs)` so that you see why we get these results):

```
>>> adjacency(pass2index('jko'))
((2, 7), (2, 8))
((2, 8), (1, 9))
2
>>> adjacency(pass2index('aqzsp'))
((2, 1), (1, 1))
((2, 1), (3, 1))
((2, 1), (2, 2))
((1, 1), (2, 2))
((3, 1), (2, 2))
5
>>> adjacency(pass2index('Kl'))
((2, 8), (2, 9))
1
>>> adjacency(pass2index('7Yu'))
((0, 7), (1, 6))
((0, 7), (1, 7))
((1, 6), (1, 7))
3
```

Comment: Hi. Although the code was indeed well commented, it is a tad too complex for me to follow with my rudimentary programming skills. From what I managed to gather, your code gets the job done and even gives pairs of adjacent characters. Later in my program, I will have needed to have stored these pairs so I will be saving your code to study further later.

I honestly cannot use it though, because I do not at all feel comfortable using something I don't fully understand. Thanks alot for your answer still; I will come back to it when my skills have developed a bit

Comment: @Kos Sure, it's always better to you the code you fully understand. Though reading through the code you are not 100% comfortable will sharpen your skills. It's even easier when someone walk you through the parts you don't quite get. So if you want, feel free to ask any specific questions about my code and I'll try to help you.